# AutoHotKey WinClose with CTRL+W

Tags: windows, autohotkey

I used the [**WinClose Script**](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinClose.htm) in AutoHotKey to close windows with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> (^w). As the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> is sometimes already the shortcut to close a window (or tab in Firefox), I send again a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> which ends then in a infinite loop I guess. How can I solve that?

This is the error message:

[image]

And this is my script:

```
;;; make the “CTRL+W” key to close window or tab.
; which key to send depends on the application
^w::
IfWinActive ahk_class ATH_Note
{ ; ATH_Note is Windows Mail
; Ctrl+F4
  Send !{F4}
}
IfWinActive ahk_class Notepad
{ ; Alt+F4
  Send !{F4}
}
Else IfWinActive ahk_class Outlook Express Browser Class
{ WinMinimize, A
}
Else IfWinActive ahk_class IrfanView
{ Send {Esc}
 }
Else ; IE, Firefox, Google Chrome, Opera
{  Send ^w
 }
Return
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would try using [context-sensitive hotkeys](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm) instead of checking the active window on keypress.  Your other hotkeys still work the same, but since your browsers are not specified, they will maintain their normal functionality.  I created your desired functionality by using the code below:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class ATH_Note
  ^w::Send !{F4}
#IfWinActive

#IfWinActive ahk_class Notepad
  ^w::Send !{F4}
#IfWinActive

#IfWinActive ahk_class Outlook Express Browser Class
  ^w::WinMinimize, A
#IfWinActive

#IfWinActive ahk_class IrfanView
  ^w::Esc
#IfWinActive
```

If there are some shared hotkeys between programs, you can also create groups:

```
GroupAdd, FileExplorer, ahk_class EVERYTHING
GroupAdd, FileExplorer, ahk_class CabinetWClass
GroupAdd, FileExplorer, ahk_class #32770

#IfWinActive ahk_group FileExplorer
    ^w::WinMinimize, A
#IfWinActive
```

Comment: Thanks good point, but the problem occurs with programs that I haven't in my script (the ELSE case). But you're right, maybe I should just do a context-sensitive script, only programs I'm aware of their hotkeys.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you don't have **return** in the if statement so that mean loop around until your script crash, also you have to put on else return, ... try this approach.

**Edited:**

```
    $^w::
IfWinActive ahk_class ATH_Note
{ ; ATH_Note is Windows Mail
; Ctrl+F4
  Send !{F4}
}
IfWinActive ahk_class Notepad
{ ; Alt+F4
  Send !{F4}
}
Else IfWinActive ahk_class Outlook Express Browser Class
{ WinMinimize, A
}
Else IfWinActive ahk_class IrfanView
{ Send {Esc}
 }  
else
{
Send ^{w}
return
}
Return
```

Use **$** to prevent triggering many times when you use **Send** command.
[$](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)

Comment: No, unfortunately if you send the ^w in the else statement (see my code), you will also end up in a loop (even with the return).

Comment: Code is edited and it's working, that will work without error and it will return when it's needed ... all the rest explanation is same