# Can we associate ESC key to always close any type of program?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I sometimes hate to move the mouse, just to hit the close button or to press ALT+F4 to terminate a running software/program or an active window. Honestly, I feel more comfortable to simply hit ESC key, (which applies to other programs). Can I make this works to all running software?

Comment: Vim users ain't gonna like you...

Comment: I can imagine there are many instances where it'd be awkward.

Comment: There are many programs where ESC is expected to bring up some sort of menu, from where you can then exit. Especially games or simulations.

Comment: May be helpful http://superuser.com/questions/488827/autohotkey-winclose-with-ctrlw

Comment: What are you going to use to replace ESC's original meanings?

Comment: It's an interesting question to ask, but odds are very, very good that you don't actually want to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It really depends on the programs you are using. So, an option which *might* work is Auto Hot Key.

However, it will have possible negative results. For example, only some programs will close with certain commands, so if you mapped <kbd>ALT</kbd> <kbd>F4</kbd> to <kbd>ESC</kbd> but a program only recognises <kbd>ALT</kbd> <kbd>F4</kbd> as the shutdown, then it won't work!

So, you could then map several commands to AutoHotKey, where hitting <kbd>ESC</kbd> sends <kbd>ESC</kbd>, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> then <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> and then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> etc (no idea how long this list would need to be). Again, the implications of this may not be desirable.

Another issue about mapping the <kbd>ESC</kbd> is what happens when you don't want to exit the program but still want to send <kbd>ESC</kbd>?

Personally, I would just learn which combination to press. However, you may be better to create a new combination, such as <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>ESC</kbd> which sends all the of the possible close commands (listed above as a guide).

Comment: I would assume you mean ALT F4? or is it CTRL F4?

Comment: So if `Alt+F4` closes the Word doc which you have open, then is the script going to be smart enough to not proceed with `Ctrl+W` right afterwards? If Windows focuses on a web browser which you have open in the background after closing the Word doc then it is going to close at least one tab. For every solution added to solve this non-problem you need to recalculate your new problems as `problems^solutions`

Comment: Surely there has to be a way for a program to intercept "ESC" and send a `SIGTERM` or `SIGQUIT` to the active application... (or WM_CLOSE or whatever it is in windows)

Comment: I'm not saying there is or isn't really.. But the OP mentions ALT F4 only, I've just explained why that may not work, and provided extra suggestions/situations and thoughts which, based upon their future research, may result in something that suffices @Cruncher .. Who knows, there may be already be an app that exists? :)

Comment: @DaveRook Let me back up a step here, I like your suggestion and think that it can be tweaked and applicable in certain ways. The purpose of my comment was to educate OP as to why this is an **[XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/235923)** and how a solution will actually create new problems. Kind of like how a person with minor but manageable back pain goes in for surgery and relieves their back problems but a week later a blood clot from the surgery is jarred and causes a debilitating stroke.

Comment: I like the comment made by David S. up in the question. Sometimes you want `Esc` to send the `Esc` signal rather than `Alt+F4` unless of course you decide to write a game that maps `Alt+F4` to perform `Esc` functionality but where does the madness end =)

Comment: @DaveRook Did a little bit of reading. It turns out that alt+f4 *does* send WM_CLOSE to the active window. Applications can ignore WM_CLOSE, but if it does so, outside of being malware, it has a good reason for it (like prompting user to save a document). So mapping to alt+f4 should be sufficient I would think. What applications don't it work on?

Comment: I wonder if this is a dupe http://superuser.com/questions/488827/autohotkey-winclose-with-ctrlw

Comment: @MonkeyZeus, sorry if my message came across 'funny', I wasn't having a go/attack etc :). Yes, I made the same point in my post (Another issue about mapping the ESC is what happens when you don't want to exit the program but still want to send ESC?)

Comment: @DaveRook it did not come across as 'funny' to me =) but I just wanted to make sure future readers don't get the wrong impression

Comment: @Cruncher, this is the point, although ALT F4 sends a command, the program can choose to ignore it, and may have it's own unique key combination...

Comment: @DaveRook I would consider any application that flat out ignores WM_CLOSE to be malicious. I would consider malicious programs to be outside of scope. WM_CLOSE doesn't just come from alt+f4... it also comes from "end task" in task manager, Or pressing the red X. Or in task bar, right clicking and clicking close.

Comment: @Cruncher Yes, good point. However, AHK may do this. You can get the [PID of the current window](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/42483-can-i-get-the-process-id-or-pid-of-the-active-window/), so, within a loop, send a command, then test if it's open, if not, move to the next command...

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to do this in Windows, download and install [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).
Open Notepad and copy+paste this line of code and save it as `.AHK` file and double click it.

```
Esc::Send !{f4}
```

If you want to, you can compile the script, which creates an executable EXE file that you can carry with you to use on any Windows machine where you want <kbd>Esc</kbd> mapped to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> key combination.

[image: ESC Remap]